# Error removing empty elements from TinyMCE editor using DOMDocument

Tags: php, domdocument

I have two questions:

1. I am using TinyMCE editor and I want to remove empty tags from HTML. I am getting error "DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : p" when I pass text from TinyMCE editor and this error disappears when I directly pass text to TinyMCE strange! Please see code below.
2. How do I prevent warning from DomDocument when incorrect HTML is passed?. `<strong>Bold Item </b></strong>`?

Here is an example text

```
<p style="text-align: justify;"> </p>
<p>blah blah blah <strong></strong>.</p>
<p style="text-align: justify;"> </p>
<p>paragraph three!!.</p>
```

My function

```
function remove_empty_tags ($text) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML($text);

    // fetch all the wanted nodes
    $xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
    foreach($xp->query('//*[not(node() or self::br) or normalize-space() = ""]') as $node) {
        $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
    }

    // output the cleaned markup
    return $dom->saveXml($dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0) );
 }

 echo remove_empty_tags($_POST['mce_editor']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using following function with `error_reporting(0)`

```
function remove_empty_tags ($text) {
    error_reporting(0); // added
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML($text);
    $xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
    foreach($xp->query('//*[not(node() or self::br) or normalize-space() = ""]') as $node) {
        $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
    }
    return $dom->saveXml($dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0) );
}
echo remove_empty_tags("<p>blah blah blah <strong><i></strong>.<em><span></em></span></p>");
```

I get following result

```
<p>blah blah blah .</p>
```

You may try this but not sure if it works for you with `TinyMCE`, [example here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/103c5c883ca8cae96b49a779a97ddf3d7765cd9f).

**Update:**
Also there is another way using [simplexml_import_dom](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-import-dom.php) to repair badly nested tags

```
error_reporting(0);
$text = "<p>blah blah blah <strong><i></strong>.<em><span></em></span></p>";
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($text);
$repaired = simplexml_import_dom($dom)->asXML();
echo $repaired;
```

which gives me following result

```
<p>blah blah blah <strong><i></i></strong><i>.<em><span></span></em></i></p>
```